# Dummy Variable in OLS regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, categorical-data

I would like to include in my OLS regression a dummy variable with two categories (d=0,d=1)and n=75. When the dummy takes the value of 1, it refers to 19 observations of the 75. Does it matter for my results? I mean because 19 observations is small number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It matters to the extent that your standard deviation will increase for that coefficient, since 75-19 of your observations of d are zero, send you have few real samples of d. This may not matter if your model is particularly precise

You may be exposed to multicolinearity if there is not enough variation in other variables, if d is 1 iff d2 is 1.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now it is clear to me